# Changing worksheet while using VLookup causes problems

Tags: vba, excel

I want to import two values in total from two different worksheets. I have the worksheets `Site1` and `Site2`. From these I want to import the values corresponding to the rows `(Product1,Cost)` and `(Product2,Cost)` respectively.

For this I've tried:

```
  Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & Path) ' It imports the correct file
  Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site1")
  currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Product1", openWs.Range("A1:R30"), Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1")))
  Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site2")
  currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Product2", openWs.Range("A1:R30"), Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1")))
```

This however gets me the error: `Error code '13'.: Incompatible types` at the second row where I run the code (referring to the worksheet Site2). When I have tried to debug this error, it seems that the error occurs when I try to call the worksheet Site2.

I have looked at the data types at the original file, and it is a number in both cases. The datatype is the same in my "ActiveWorkbook" as well. I've tried using a new `Set openws2 = openWb.Sheets("Site2")` and adapting the code to that, but it still caused the same error.

What am I doing wrong when trying to use VLookup at worksheet Site2?

Edit: Edited to reflect Changes to make VLookup span multiple columns + adding "WorksheetFunction" as a prefix to VLookup.

Edit2: I have now ran my code line to line (using `F8`). Adding `MsgBox Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1"))` before and after the line `Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site2")` returned the correct column index for worksheet "Site1", but did not return anything at all after I change openWs to Site2. Does this mean that it is not possible to conduct the command `Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site2)` in the mannor I have done - i.e. will the program not recognize this as merely opening up a new sheet?

Edit3: Basically each Worksheets consists of an Array where A1 is empty, and A2:A30 consists of row headings of productnames - Product1, Product2, ...., Product30. The range A1:R1 consists of column headers of Quantity, Costs, etc. I want to use Application.Match in combination of VLookup as a way of avoiding "mismatching" of columns in case some other user inserts a, say, new column. I therefore use VLookup, first to find the row for which "product1" is located in, and then using Application.Match I can find which column "Cost" is located in. Through this I ought to find, and I also do find, the value corresponding to the (row,column) index (Product1,Cost). The problem arises when I want to use the new worksheet, "Site2". Simply adapting the code to capture "Product2,Cost" in this worksheet should work (I think). Instead I get an error, which I have tried to debug and if I understand it correct it stems from the fact that the program doesn't translate `Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site2")` into what I wanted to achieve, simply a new worksheet to conduct the same type of Vlookup formula on.

EDIT4: Due to the fact that the problems may been caused by a specialcharacter `å` when I try to import the data from the sheet I call `Site2` (which in reality is different, and includes an `å` - let's henceforth call it Site2å in order to try to use wildcards), I've tried some different approaches.

Neither using

```
 set openWs = openWb.Sheets(3) '3 is the index of `Site2å`
```

or

```
 For Each openWs In openWb.Worksheets
      If LCase(openWs.Name) Like "Site2?" Then
              openWs.Select
              Exit For
      End If
 Next openWs
```

works. The latter gives the error `Object or With variable not set`. I have defined openWs as `Dim openWs as Worksheet`

Comment: First, in your fourth line, you have a type error, you mean `currentwb` , and not `current.wb`. Secondly, the VLookup function should be modified to `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Comment: @ShaiRado      Thanks! I have updated my OP to reflect these changes. The problem persists though.

Comment: Your updated code does not also correct all instances of 'current.wb' to 'currentwb'. That should fix the remaining problem.

Comment: @PaaquaGrant   I wrote the code containing currentWb manually as I had to rewrite so much anyway in order to make the code easier to read. In my code I execute the currentWb is written correctly, and the error still arises.

Comment: Are "Product1" and "Product2" supposed to be variables, or are there literally row headings called "Product1" and "Product2" for which you are looking for the cost?

Comment: @Gustav Danell not sure what you meant in your `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` function. The third parameter you have is `Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1"))`, it should return a number of how many columns to the right of where _Product_ is found. When I tried it and just entered manually 2, I got a legal value back to my cell.

Comment: @Gustav Danell  can you add a screenshot of your data in Site1 worksheet ?

Comment: With a cell in column A equal to "Product1", and a column header in row 1 equal to "Cost" I was able to run the code without problems.

Comment: @PaaquaGrant   The code runs and returns the correct value using "Site1". However, when I want to use "Site2" worksheet I get the error. Product1 and Product2 are merely row headings, and the objective is to find the cost for these.

Comment: Does your Workbook actually have a tab named "Site2"?  Furthermore, unless there is only a single line of data on each sheet, you need some serious modification to your code if you want to pull the costs in for a specific item. If you do have only a single line, then you don't need VLOOKUP, you can simply pull the value from the cell directly below "Cost".

Comment: @PaaquaGrant   It actually works as intended. I get the row number from Product1, and the column number from Cost, and I can deduce the value corresponding to it. The problem arises when I want to use Site2 instead of Site1. The Worksheet itself is actually not Site2. I want to be "descrete" as I conduct this program from work. The sheet itself uses the character `å` come to think of it. I have not had any troubles with it up until now. Can VLookup have troubles with special characters like `å`?

Comment: VLOOKUP isn't having the trouble, but if that worksheet uses a special character in the name, when you try to assign that sheet to the variable 'openws' it will fail. when referring to a sheet name in code it must be **EXACTLY** the same as the sheet name in the workbook (which is why using hard-coded worksheet names is not recommended).

Comment: @PaaquaGrant   Thanks for investing this much time into this. I tried to avoid directly importing the specific worksheet containing `å` but without any success. EDIT4 describes what I've tried in that aspect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114123/discussion-between-paaqua-grant-and-gustav-danell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a solution for this problem. I post this as an answer as I've been under the impression that VLookup or Application.Match along with the switch in worksheets caused the problems, and after googling this issue found out that some other code authors has believed the same.

For me the solution was simply to Close the workbook used before changing the worksheet. In my code I have added the minor adjustments to the code.

```
  Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & Path) ' It imports the correct file
  Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site1")
  currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Product1", openWs.Range("A1:R30"), Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1")))
  openWb.Close saveChanges:=False    ' Added this line
  Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Site2")
  currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3,3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Product2", openWs.Range("A1:R30"), Application.Match("Cost", openWs.Range("A1:R1")))
  openWb.Cloe saveChanges:=False     'And this one
```

Hopefully this can be of any help to anyone else! I sure had to google quite some time before realizing I was looking in the wrong place.

(And I'd like to thank @PaaquaGrant for investing so much time in this topic, and being a very nice person to talk to).

Answer (score 1):

Your VLOOKUP range is a single Column, instead of a multi-column range. This will always fail.

As suggested in some of the comments, you also need to adjust all instances of `current.wb` to `currentwb.`

Comment: Thanks for answer! These changes did not eliminate the problem. However +1 for useful information.