# Application.Match returns the wrong column number

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use `Application.Match` along with VBA in order to find a column number, and subsequently use this as a parameter in Another function.

My code thus far is:

```
 Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(filepath & Path)
 Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1") 
 Set currentWb = ActiveWorkbook

 currentWb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,3).Value = Application.Match("Delivered", openWs.Range("A2:R2"),0)
```

Where the array `A2:R2` contains a set of headers for the columns. In my example the "Delivered" header is in M2, or column number 13. My issue is that the function returns the value of 2 indicating that the "Delivered" column ought to be in B2.

I know that Application.Match returns a Relative position, but having the range span from A2 to R2 should avoid any issue in regards to that. There is only one column with the text "Delivered".

I hope someone can shed some light into this

Regards

Comment: What is in B2 on Sheet1?

Comment: @Rory          All columns A2 through R2 merely contains a text string. In the particular case of B2 it's `Stock levels 20160531`

Comment: I've never seen `Match` do that. Are you sure `currentWb` is the one you think it is - typically the workbook you just opened would be the active workbook.

Comment: @Rory          OK, this is strange. As a workaround for an issue caused when importing data from a specific worksheet from a workbook, and subsequently changing the worksheet to import data from (confer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678650/changing-worksheet-while-using-vlookup-causes-problems) I closed the file, and then opened it up again using the new worksheet. However, using this approach in this case (I imported some data from another worksheet earlier in the code) caused Match to work like this (I'm assuming currentWb was not ActiveWorkbook as you proposed).

Comment: @Rory          Now the program shows the wrong column number again when Printing the Application.Match formula. However, it imports the correct values from the correct Column number!

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked what is in C2 on Sheet1 of the workbook you are performing the match on?

Comment: @Rory          Please consider posting the hint that currentWb in fact may be another workbook than the one I intended, so I can accept that answer. It seems like adjusting the external links solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `currentWb` is the one you think it is? Typically the workbook you just opened would be the active workbook, so you probably need to assign that to the variable *before* you open the source workbook.